# Functioncall to javascript not working

Tags: php, javascript, html, function

i'm using php to generate some button that have their Id and the Id of the text they should show as parameters. But for some reason the function call doesn't seem to be working.

> while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
>     {
>       $reviewDoor=$row[0];
>       $korteTekst=$row[1];
>       $langeTekst=$row[2];
>
> ```
> echo "<article><h4>Review van $reviewDoor</h4>";
> echo "<section>$korteTekst</section>";
> if (!empty($langeTekst))
> {
> echo "<section id='LongReview$teller' class='LongReviews'>$langeTekst</section>";
> echo "<button id='LeesMeerKnop$teller' class='LeesMeerKnoppen' onclick='readMoreLess(LeesMeerKnop$teller,LongReview$teller)'>Lees meer...</button>";
> }
> echo "</article>";
>     $teller++;
> ```
>
> }

the file link is working

> ```
> <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> ```

and this is the function I'm trying to call

> function readMoreLess(knopId,tekst) {
>
> var knop=getElementById(knopId);
>         var review=getElementById(tekst);
>
> window.alert("hallo");
>
> if (knop.textContent ==="Lees meer...")
>         {
>            knop.textContent="Minder tekst...";
>            review.style.display="block";
>     }
>          else if (knop.textContent ==="Minder tekst...")
>         {
>         knop.textContent="Lees meer..."; 
>                 review.style.display="none";
>         }
>         }

Comment: So, what's the error console log saying in your browser? Why are you not calling `getElementById` on the `document` as you should? And please, while Dutch is a great language, try to be at least **slightly** consistent. Either use English like the rest of the world or name all your variables, IDs and functions in your own language.

Comment: ow damn, thanks :p but it's  still not working :S i'm not even getting an alert

Comment: You also need to apply @Eugene's fix below. Both these problems will have been clear and visible in your error log in the browser.

Comment: did that too, and still nothin, this is what the console says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: but the brackets seem to be right :S

Comment: Check previous JS code/scripts, if they exists

Comment: It also lists an exact line number, and doubleclicking will show exactly which one was 'unexpected'. Debugging 101.

Comment: it did seem to be the quotes, i thought '' quotes would have the same effect as " " quotes, so thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like missing quotes on params values in function call:

```
 echo "<button id='LeesMeerKnop$teller' class='LeesMeerKnoppen' onclick='readMoreLess(\"LeesMeerKnop$teller\",\"LongReview$teller\")'>Lees meer...</button>";
```

Comment: added quotes and and document. before the getelement function but it's still doing nothing :S